# Validate input text with jQuery following different rules

Tags: jquery, validation

I have an input text into a form where I write an alphanumeric code, that I must validate. 
So, after I wrote the text, when I click on the submit button

```
if there is an error in the text 
    it will be displayed an error message
else 
    there will be a submit and success message
```

The rules to follow are:

- The length of code must be 27. Not less, not more.

  AA BB C DDDDD EEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFF
- AA must be "IT" (uppercase).
- BB are numbers (even with the initial zero).
- C is a character (uppercase).
- DDDDD are numbers (even with the initial zero).
- EEEEE are numbers (even with the initial zero).
- FFFFFFFFFFFF are characters and numbers. It's sufficient that the length is 12.

How can I validate the code and write this rules with jQuery?

Comment: Please do not use the jquery-validate tag unless your question is specifically about this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a function to help you get where you need to be with your password rules.  I will leave it up to you to implement it with your form submission because I am not sure how you plan on implementing that part of your application.

**Update:**  I added code to remove white space from input string before checking the rule conditions.

**Reason:**  If white space is allowed in the input a blank space will count as part of the number checks and return true.

jsfiddle [Validate Input with Special Rules](https://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/tk7an8do/)

Test HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Test JavaScript:

```
/*
The rules to follow are:

The length of code must be 27. Not less, not more.

AA BB C DDDDD EEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFF

AA must be "IT" (uppercase). first 2 characters

BB are numbers (even with the initial zero).  3 & 4 characters
C is a character (uppercase). 5th character
DDDDD are numbers (even with the initial zero). characters 5 - 10 
EEEEE are numbers (even with the initial zero). characters 11 - 15
FFFFFFFFFFFF are characters and numbers. It's sufficient that the length is 12.
characters 16 - 27 above
*/

var input = "IT12C1234567891FFFFFFFFFFFF";

validate(input);


function validate(input){//begin function

     //remove all of the white space from the input
     var input = input.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    //test for length
    var testLength = input.length === 27;

    //2nd and 3rd characters equal IT
    var AA = input.substring(0,2) === "IT";

    //3rd and 4th characters are numbers
    var BB = !isNaN(input.substring(2,4));

    //The 5th character is a non numerical capitalized character
    var C = isNaN(input.split("")[4]) && input.split("")[4] === input.split("")[4].toUpperCase();

    //characters 5 - 10 are numbers
    var DDDDD = !isNaN(input.substring(5,10));

    //characters 11- 15 are numbers
    var EEEEE = !isNaN(input.substring(10,15));

    //characters 16 - 27 can be characters and numbers as long as the length is 12
    var FFFFFFFFFFFF = input.substring(15,27).length === 12;

    //if all the password rules checks return true
    if(testLength && AA && BB && C & DDDDD && EEEEE & FFFFFFFFFFFF){//begin if then


        //do what you need to do here if the password is valid

    }
    else{


        //let the user know the error here


    }


    //display test results
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = testLength + "<br>" 
        + AA + "<br>"
        + BB + "<br>"
        + C + "<br>"
        + DDDDD + "<br>"
        + EEEEE + "<br>"
        + FFFFFFFFFFFF + "<br>";  



}//end function
```

Comment: Not a problem. Check out the update I made. There is another check I put in for you that will save you a lot of headaches later on.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to remove the white spaces also when I copy and paste. But it's not working. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzftjz58/), how can I solve it?

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like this  https://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/gavua9zb/

Comment: Not a problem if you need any more help send me a message at bytewarestudios.com/contact